# Library cannot have applicationId, and cannot find package name in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, maven, gradle, migrate

I'm trying to migrate an old maven project to gradle because Google apparently decided to drop support for the old build method previously this year.

I've moved most of the library already but I'm experiencing an issue with a library project that is not in a "jar" file;

I have this in my root `settings.gradle`;

```
include ':app'
include ':ZBarScannerLibrary'
```

It recognizes the ZBarScannerLibrary and I've setup this gradle build in `ZBarScannerLibrary/build.gradle`;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
}
```

When I try to build the app it says

> Error: Cannot read packageName from ./ZBarScannerLibrary/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Fine I think, and I add an applicationId to the build gradle;
`applicationId "com.dm.zbar.android.scanner"`

Instead, I'm now presented with the error message;

> Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':ZBarScannerLibrary'.
>   Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.dm.zbar.android.scanner' in default config.

So if I leave the applicationId out of gradle, it complains that it cannot read a package name, and if i tell it the package name it says a library cannot have an applicationId.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by including the requested AndroidManifest.xml file, `./ZBarScannerLibrary/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, containing something like:

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pkg.zbar.blah" />`

Comment: I'm facing same issue, but the still error persists.